# Changing the sequential probabilities but reaching the same final states - possible?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, discrete-mathematics

I am not very good at math-speak and I hope my explanation is clear below. I will provide an example & hopefully I am not missing something obvious in thinking about this problem.

Question:

Consider the case where you have the following distribution;

$A : P(A)$

$B : P(B)$

$P(A) + P(B) = 1.$

furthermore, in the case of A, events C,D,E and F follow, again with P(C),P(D),P(E) AND P(F) so that you have sum of P(C), ... , P(F) = 1. i.e in all events A - F all scenarios are accounted for. Worth noting here that there does not necessarily have to be 4 different sub-events, although I think that the scenario changes once you have more than 2.

Anyway, now we have something like this;

$P(A)*P(C) + P(A)*P(B) + P(A)*P(C) + P(A)*P(D) + P(B) = 1.$

my question is this;

Is it possible to re-represent this using 4 different events over 4 different combinations of the events, combining them to reach the same end states?

i.e

$P(X)^4 = P(A)*P(C)$

$P(Y)^4 = P(A)*P(D)$

$P(Z)^4 = P(A)*P(E)$

$P(W)^4 = P(A)*P(F)$

and that P(B) is equal to all "mismatching" sequences. i.e $P(B) = 1 - (P(X)^4 + P(Y)^4 + P(Z)^4 + P(W)^4)$.

One way to ask is under which conditions can you take the 4th root of all P(C), P(D), P(E), P(F) and still have the result + P(B) = 1,

Furthermore, does this become simpler if the X,Y,Z or W probabilities can differ, i.e $P(X1)*P(X2)*P(X3)*P(X4) = P(A)*P(C), but P(X1) + P(Y1) + P(Z1) + P(W1) = 1$ etc..

In an example -

On a game show you have 1 bag with white balls and black balls. If you reach in and grab get a white ball you win prize A with probability A, prize B with probability B, prize C with probability C and prize D with probability D. A black ball gets you nothing.

The game show host wants to change the game but not the probability of winning the prizes. He wants to have 4 bags, each bag has a ball with A, B, C or D on it. The player pics on ball from each bag and is only awarded a prize if all of the balls match, otherwise gets nothing.

Question - is this possible?

Another example for fun...

An intruder with a random hand (haha...) changes the switches in your house.

You have initially a switch that could go on or off. It is on with probability P(A) and off with probability P(B). When it is on there is a probability P(C) that the light is green, P(D) that the light is red, P(E) that the light is blue and P(F) that the light is yellow.

You want to make things easier for your intruder.

You rebuild the house and now you have 4 switches, and each switch has 4 states, one for every colour. If all the switches are on the same colour, the light shines with that colour. If there are any mismatches the light is off.

Is your intruder able to re-create the probability of the final states of the lights every time that you walk in after he has been there?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial.  To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: hi @saulspatz , there areno images in the question - when I have a bit of time tomorrow i'll edit it for some better looking LaTex but the question above is all text.

Comment: @saulspatz lets see if the tag worksthis time!

Comment: I don't really follow this. Say in the game show there are originally $w$ white balls and $b$ black ones.  To do the same thing with $4$ sacks, just add three sacks with all white balls.  I don't suppose this is what you're looking for, but nothing you say excludes it, so far as I can see.

Comment: It is not clear to me what "final state" or "end state" means in connection with a (discrete) probability distribution.  The "example" of a game suggests these terms are connected with how such a game ends, but the basic setup of a probability distribution is that probabilities are assigned to outcomes and nothing makes one outcome any more "final" than another.  So try to edit the Question to setup the problem more clearly for your Readers.